# compare product functionality not allowed for non-registered user in magento

Tags: compare

When non-registred user clicking on add to compare then it shows the alert for registration (with message "registration is required"). Please help. I am using magento 1.9. anybody knows answer please share.

this is my list.phtml file

```
<?php  
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();   
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');  

//var_dump(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName());  
//get list layout
$currentCat = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getName();
//echo $currentCat;exit;
if ('Retail POS Software' == $currentCat && !$this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
$displayMode =  'list';  
} else {
$displayMode =  $this->getMode();
}
//get list layout end
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<?php if (!$this->getRequest()->isAjax()): ?>
<div id="ajax-errors" style="display: none;">
<ul class="messages">
    <li class="error-msg">
        <ul>
            <li><span><?php echo $this->__('An error occurred, please try again later.'); ?></span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
 </div>
 <div id="loading" style="display: none; margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: center;">
<img class="v-middle" alt="" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/loader  
shopby.gif'); ?>"> <?php echo $this->__('Loading, please wait...'); ?>
</div>
<div id="catalog-listing">
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="category-products">

<div class="toolbar-top">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
<?php // List mode 
    //change $this->getMode() to $displayMode
    ?>

<div class="yt-products-container clearfix">
    <?php if($displayMode!='grid'): ?>
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ol class="products-list" >
        <?php 
        $count_input_qty = 0;
        foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): 
        $count_input_qty++;
        $now = date("Y-m-d");
        $newsFrom= substr($_product->getData('news_from_date'),0,10);
        $newsTo=  substr($_product->getData('news_to_date'),0,10);
        $specialprice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialPrice();
        $price = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getPrice();
        $saleoff= round(($price - $specialprice)/$price*100) ;
        ?>
        <li class="item <?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="product-list-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product-img" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>">
                            <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                            src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(300,300); ?>"
                            alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                        </a>

                        <?php if ( $now>=$newsFrom && $now<=$newsTo ){ ?>
                            <span class="new-product have-ico"><?php echo $this->__('New'); ?></span>
                        <?php }
                        if ( $specialprice ){ ?>
                            <span class="sale-product have-ico"><?php echo $this->__('Sale'); ?></span>
                        <?php } ?>                          
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-info col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="product-name">
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>">
                        <?php if( strlen($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')) > 100 ){
                                 echo substr($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'), 0, 100);
                            } else {
                                echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
                            }?>
                        </a>
                    </div>   
                    <div class="product-review">
                        <?php  echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, "short", true); ?>
                    </div>                     
                    <div class="product-price">
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    </div>      

                    <?php
                        // Provides extra blocks on which to hang some features for products in the list
                        // Features providing UI elements targeting this block will display directly below the product name
                        if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                            $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                            foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                                $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                                $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                                echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                            }
                        }
                    ?>

                    <?php if($_product->getshort_description()) { ?>
                    <div class="product-desciption">
                        <?php echo $_product->getshort_description();?>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>  

                    <?php /* if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; */?>
                    <div class="product-addto-wrap">
                            <div class="product-addcart">
                                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>                                    
                                    <a class="btn-cart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to cart') ?>" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')">
                                        <?php echo $this->__('Add to cart') ?>
                                    </a>                                                                    
                                <?php endif; ?>                             
                            </div>
                            <div class="wishlist-compare">
                                <?php if ( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() ) : ?>
                                <a class="link-wishlist" href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>">
                                    <?php //echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>
                                </a>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if( $_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product) ): ?>

                                <a class="link-compare" href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare'); ?>">
                                    <?php //echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>
                                </a>

                                <?php endif;?>
                            </div>
                        </div>                                          
                </div>                                                          
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>

    <?php else: ?>
    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount();?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):?>
    <?php 
    $now = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");
    $newsFrom= $_product->getNewsFromDate();
    $newsTo=  $_product->getNewsToDate();
    $specialprice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialPrice();
    $price = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getPrice();
    $special_from_date = $_product->getSpecialFromDate();
    $special_to_date = $_product->getSpecialToDate();
    ?>
    <?php if ( $i++ == 0 ){ ?>
    <div class="products-grid">
        <div class="row">
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="item-inner">

                    <div class="product-image">
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                            <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                            src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(300,300); ?>"
                            alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                        </a>

                        <?php
                        // Provides extra blocks on which to hang some features for products in the list
                        // Features providing UI elements targeting this block will display directly below the product name
                        if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                            $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                            foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                                $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                                $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                                echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                            }
                        }
                        ?>

                        <?php if ( $now>=$newsFrom && $now<=$newsTo ){ ?>
                            <span class="new-product have-ico"><?php echo $this->__('New'); ?></span>
                        <?php }
                        if ( $specialprice ){ ?>
                            <span class="sale-product have-ico"><?php echo $this->__('Sale'); ?></span>
                        <?php } ?>                          
                    </div>

                    <div class="product-info">
                        <div class="product-name">
                            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>">
                            <?php if( strlen($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')) > 60 ){
                                 echo substr($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'), 0, 60).'...more';
                            } else {
                                echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
                            }?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-review">
                            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, "short", true); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-price">
                            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="product-addto-wrap">
                            <div class="product-addcart">
                                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>

                                    <a class="btn-cart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to cart') ?>" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')">
                                        <?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>
                                    </a>

                                <?php else: ?>
                                <p class="availability out-of-stock">
                                    <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?> </span>
                                </p>
                                <?php endif; ?>                             
                            </div>
                            <div class="wishlist-compare">
                                <?php if ( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() ) : ?>
                                <a class="link-wishlist" href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>">
                                    <?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>
                                </a>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if( $_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product) ): ?>

                                <a class="link-compare" href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare'); ?>">
                                    <?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>
                                </a>

                                <?php endif;?>
                            </div>
                        </div>                          
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
    <?php if ( $i == $_collectionSize ){ ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<div class="toolbar-bottom">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
</div>

</div>    
<?php if (!$this->getRequest()->isAjax()): ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?phpif($this->helper('sm_shopby')->isAjaxEnabled()&&!$this->getRequest()->isAjax()):?>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function pushState(data, link, replace) {
    var History = window.History;
    if ( !History.enabled ) {
        return false;
    }

    if (replace) {
        History.replaceState(data, document.title, link);
    } else {
        History.pushState(data, document.title, link);
    }
}

function handleEvent(el, event) {
    var url, fullUrl;
    if (typeof el === 'string') {
        url = el;
    } else if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
        url = $(el).readAttribute('href');
    } else if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'select') {
        url = $(el).getValue();
    }

    <?php // Add this to query string for full page caching systems ?>
    if (url.indexOf('?') != -1) {
        fullUrl = url + '&isLayerAjax=1';
    } else {
        fullUrl = url + '?isLayerAjax=1';
    }

    $('loading').show();
    $('ajax-errors').hide();

    pushState(null, url, false);

    new Ajax.Request(fullUrl, {
        method: 'get',
        onSuccess: function(transport) {
            if (transport.responseJSON) {                    
                $('catalog-listing').update(transport.responseJSON.listing);
                $('layered-navigation').update(transport.responseJSON.layer);
                pushState({
                    listing: transport.responseJSON.listing,
                    layer: transport.responseJSON.layer
                }, url, true);
                ajaxListener();
            } else {
                $('ajax-errors').show();
            }
            $('loading').hide();
        }
    });

    if (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
function ajaxListener() {
    var els;
    els = $$('div.pager-wrapper a').concat(
        $$('div.sort-by-wrap a'),
        $$('div.view-mode-wrap a'),
       // $$('div.pager select'),
        $$('div.sorter select'),
        $$('div.block-layered-nav a')
    );
    els.each(function(el) {
        if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
            $(el).observe('click', function(event) {
                handleEvent(this, event);
            });
        } else if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'select') {
            $(el).setAttribute('onchange', '');
            $(el).observe('change', function(event) {
                handleEvent(this, event);
            });
        }
    });
}
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    ajaxListener();

    (function(History) {
        if ( !History.enabled ) {
            return false;
        }

        pushState({
            listing: $('catalog-listing').innerHTML,
            layer: $('layered-navigation').innerHTML
        }, document.location.href, true);

        // Bind to StateChange Event
        History.Adapter.bind(window, 'popstate', function(event) {
            if (event.type == 'popstate') {
                var State = History.getState();
                $('catalog-listing').update(State.data.listing);
                $('layered-navigation').update(State.data.layer);
                ajaxListener();
            }
        });
    })(window.History);
});
//]]>
</script>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()){ ?>


<?php } ?>

<?php
// Provides a block where additional page components may be    attached,primarily     good for in-page JavaScript
if ($this->getChild('after')) {
$_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after')->getSortedChildren();
foreach ($_afterChildren as $_afterChildName) {
    $_afterChild = $this->getChild('after')->getChild($_afterChildName);
    //set product collection on after blocks
    $_afterChild->setProductCollection($_productCollection);
    echo $_afterChild->toHtml();
}
}
?>
```

**Updated**

I have made changes in **add to compare** button like this,

```
 <?php 
   if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
 <?php if( $_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product) ): ?>

                            <a class="link-compare" href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare'); ?>">
                                <?php //echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>
                            </a>

                            <?php endif;?>
                            }
                            else
                            {
    <?php echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Registration is required for compare product"); </script>?>

  }
         ?>
```

Comment: please share a part of code to see what you have tried so far

Comment: i already have add to compare functionality. i just want this functionality enable only those user who have registered on site and when non-registered user clicking on "add to compare"  button then they will show alert like "registration is required"

Comment: Yes,It's better if you could provide more details about your question ,because I sense that some may down vote your question due to the same reason I mentioned above

Comment: @RahalKanishka  please see updated post .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution after long time.

I have added following code at the place of compare button

```
<?php if( $_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product) ): ?>
                            <?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) { ?>
                            <a class="link-compare" href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare'); ?>"></a>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <a class="link-compare loginToCompare" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare'); ?>"></a>
                        <?php } ?>
                            <?php endif;?>
```

and added following jquery at the bottom of page for redirection of login page or create account

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $(".loginToCompare").click(function(){
     var r = confirm("You can not compare product without registration please click ok to login or create account!");
    if (r == true) {
         window.location.href="/customer/account/login/";
    }       
});
});
```

this is really working fine for me.